# Center list items horizontally across various widths

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

I have this container:

```
export const Container = styled.section<ContainerProps>`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
`;
```

Which is centering my 3 list items vertically. No matter the width of the page, it's always in the center. I'm trying to achieve the same effect but horizontally. I've tried using **float: left;** along with controlling the **margins** and that does work but then the problem is that it doesn't change dynamically with different widths (mobile).

I'm using the following the style the cards within the container. As I have said, it's 3 cards:

```
export const Card = styled.article`
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: solid 1px #e6e6e6;
  font-size: 12px;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 10px grey;
`;
```

This is the section of the return in the component:

```
        if (name !== null) {
          return (
            <Container>
              <Card>
                <CollectionAvatar
                  image={image}
                  /*name={name || collection}*/
                  type="collection"
                />
                <br></br>
                <br></br>
                {name}
              </Card>
            </Container>
          );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work for centering a div on a page horizontally and align the children in a row.

```
   .card {
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: solid 1px #e6e6e6;
  font-size: 12px;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 10px grey;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;

}

<div class="container">

<div class="card">
  <br></br>
  <br></br>
  {name}
</div>

<div class="card">
  <br></br>
  <br></br>
  {name}
</div>

<div class="card">
  <br></br>
  <br></br>
  {name}
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVPuR.png)

Comment: This is still keeping my items in a column (vertical) rather than a row (horizontal)

Comment: okay i see so to achieve that simply setting the parent container to flex will line them horizontaly. I updated the answer to show the HTML the container has to be the parent of the cards.

Comment: I'm still getting the same result. I updated my original post and simplified it to see if you can see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I haven't been able to recreate the vertical alignment unless i remove the display: flex;. Can you check the image i linked to see if that is what you want to achieve?

Comment: Also what does the output html look like when you inspect it?